# What does Chromium/Firefox use instead of Angle on MacOSX?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, firefox, webgl

Since both *Chromium* and *Firefox* are using *Angle* as their *OpenGL ES 2.0* compat layer in Windows, I am wondering, what they are using on *MacOSX*, since all that is available there is *OpenGL 3.2* (which is not compatible with *OpenGL ES 2.0*).

Are both crafting their own layer and how do they work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both use their own layer.

Both use ANGLE on all platforms as a shader validator (to validate the shader meets all the rules of WebGL) and as a shader translator (to translate the shader from WebGL GLSL to OpenGL GLSL)

Both also take various other steps to emulate OpenGL ES 2.0 on top of OpenGL like enforcing npot restrictions, limiting access to non WebGL features, etc...

Comment: Does Angle really do shader translation?

Comment: Could you pointer out where the code for shader translation is?

Comment: It's in this folder

https://code.google.com/p/angleproject/source/browse/trunk#trunk%2Fsrc%2Fcompiler  There are 3 translators in that folder. The API for the translator is in https://code.google.com/p/angleproject/source/browse/trunk/include/GLSLANG/ShaderLang.h

There's also a WebGL extension to get the translated shader. http://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/WEBGL_debug_shaders/  It's a privileged extension so normally it's not available. On chrome launch with --enable-privileged-webgl-extensions